# Encapsulated calls in php

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I have a project where I am in need of a specific piece of logic, but I am unsure how to express it in OOP php. I have seen things similar to what I need to do in frameworks like Laravel.

Here is an example of how a framework does it:

```
return View::make("index")->with("name", $name);
```

So basically I want a static base class `Fruit` with a public function `type` that can be used and set independently as a string, such as the following:

```
return Fruit::type("apple");
```

Furthermore, I want a 'modifier' sub-call that lets me add another string to that function `Fruit::type`  where the function is aware if the sub-call is made and it's return value. Kind of like this:

```
return Fruit::type("apple")->quality("outerColor", $color);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A call such as `Fruit::type("apple")` means that there's a static function call to the class Fruit. As such, you'll need something like this:

```php
class Fruit
{
    public static function type($fruitType)
    {
        if ($fruitType === 'apple') {
            $object = new Apple();
        }

        return $object;
    }
}
```

What you call a `sub-call` is actually just method chaining. As such, your `type` function in Fruit class needs to return an object that we can operate on further. In this example we can have an Apple class to do this:

```php
class Apple
{
    private $qualities = [];

    public function quality($key, $value)
    {
        $this->qualities[$key] = $param;

        return $this;
    }
}
```